# Bloquear encerramento de aplicativo android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo gerencial para Android, utilizando C# com Xamarin. 
Existe alguma forma de bloquear o aplicativo (ou bloquear todos os botões do tablet) para que o usuário não consiga encerra-lo, salvo com alguma autorização por senha. O usuário não pode utilizar mais nada do tablet, somente o aplicativo em questão.
Alguém poderia me auxiliar de como proceder com essa operação ?

Comment: Você não pode, o controle do Android deve ser pelo usuário e não pelo aplicativo, mas existem alguns "hacks gambiarras" como aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android

Comment: É possível! Chama-se Kiosk mode. Recomendo esse link: http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/